# MongoDB does not install on CentOS 6.7

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

I'm Windows guy. When I need to use Linux based OS, I always choose Ubuntu. However, this time they didn't give me any choice.

I tried to install MongoDB from this [link of mongodb site](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#for-the-latest-stable-release-of-mongodb). I have created repository file then I try to install it and I get this error message:

```
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.2.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.2)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.2.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.2)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.2.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.2)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.2.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.2)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.2.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.2)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.2.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.2)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
```

According to this message I thought that I'm missing `libstdc++.so.6`. So I have run this command to install it:

```
 yum install libstdc++.so.6
```

I got this message:

```
Package libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
```

This is getting frustrating. Why this is happening?

Comment: There is something strange with the package names, indicating that you installed the repos for Amazon Linux. Please doublecheck that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You screwed up your repository definitions a bit. Either you actually do run CentOS, in which case you mistakenly defined the repository for the AmazonLinux packages of MongoDB. This is the more likely case, since I can reproduce your problem with that misconfigured repo.

There is a chance, however, that you run on AmazonLinux and defined the CentOS repositories.

## If you are positively sure you are really on CentOS

The problem is that you entered the wrong repository. When using the correct repo, MongoDB installs and runs as expected. However, the RPM name is different, both as shown below:

[image: Working setup]

Most likely, you have put a wrong repo definition somehwere, like below:

[image: Wrong repository]

So, what you need to do is to find the place where the repository for Amazon Linux is defined and replace it with the correct one:

```
$ grep -l amazon -R /etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

The problem here is that multiple repositories might be defined. Inspect the files returned by the `grep` command, and remove the respective repository definition. Then, add the [correct repository definition](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#for-the-latest-stable-release-of-mongodb), which as of the time of this writing is

```
[mongodb-org-3.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

## If you are on AmazonLinux

### Misconception

It has to be said that

> **AmazonLinux != CentOS**

They are close (both based on RHEL), but not identical. Specifically, some package versions might differ. The package versions used to compile MongoDB for AmazonLinux are documented within the RPM, and this documentation is sort of a contract between the package and the system

> I, MongoDB, promise to run properly on a system which has these packages in the specified version.

A contract which CentOS can not fulfill.

### Solution

Simply [follow the installation instructions for MongoDB on AmazonLinux](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the culprit is glibc can you try

```
yum list glibc
```

And see if the version matches what mongo expects. Welcome to dependency hell :)

Comment: It shows me `glibc.i686 2.12-1.166.el6_7.3` and `glibc.x86_64  2.12-1.166.el6_7.3`

Comment: OK, Centos usually doesn't carry the latest versions of libs. Trying to install them would be like lighting a match stick near a pile of gunpowder. If you aren't using any killer features of mongo 3.x release you may want to stick with 2.6 version or so and see if it helps.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/administration/production-notes/ 2.6 would cut it on Centos 6.7 without causing a disaster.

Comment: @JVXR Using the correct repo for CentOS might help OP, too ;)